# MySQL and go-ircevent

Tags: go, irc

I'm new to golang and i'm trying to impliment MySQL lookup for multiple connections, however I keep getting an error using the below code.

*cannot use irc.IRC("goTest", "goTee") (type *irc.Connection) as type string in assignment*

*result[0]* is the network name

If i change
   `result[0] = irc.IRC("goTest", "goTee")`
to
    `conn := irc.IRC("goTest", "goTee")`
it works fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
"fmt"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
"github.com/thoj/go-ircevent"
)

func main() {

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", sqllogin()+":"+sqlpasswd()+"@("+sqlip()+":"+sqlport()+")/"+sqlgodb())

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM `network` ")

cols, err := rows.Columns()

rawResult := make([][]byte, len(cols))
result := make([]string, len(cols))
fmt.Println(rawResult)
dest := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
for i, _ := range rawResult {
    dest[i] = &rawResult[i]
}

for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(dest...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to scan row", err)
        return
    }

    for i, raw := range rawResult {
        if raw == nil {
            result[i] = ""
        } else {
            result[i] = string(raw)
        }
    }
    result[0] = irc.IRC("goTest", "goTee")

    result[0].Connect("ip:port")

}
    result[0].Loop()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types don't match.

`result := make([]string, len(cols))` Here you make result to be a slice of strings

`result[0] = irc.IRC("goTest", "goTee")` You are trying to put a pointer to a connection into a string.

Comment: So which way would be best to handle different network names as a result. Would I be best to leave result and try appending the strings to the connection. Or maybe making the connection a string. Thank you for your input.

Comment: If what you want to have at the end is an IRC.Connection for each of the rows in the results from the database, you are going to need yet another array (Of type *IRC.Connection to hold pointers to them), and call irc.IRC() on each of the indexes of that array using the data from the database.

Comment: With each call of irc.IRC() it requires a Loop() to keep the connection active. If I have the same Loop() command..for example conn.Loop(), It only connects to the first call of irc.IRC and not the others. How would I go about having it loop to different connections.